# Save date and time into a access file while the user submits the results

Tags: javascript, sql, asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to save date or time into a database file when the user submit the personal results. 
Currently, I am able to save all other information using the UPDATE function except the date or time. I know there are functions called date() and now() for date manipulation. But I just cannot get it right. And don't worry too much about SQL injection; this is just for my own use.

Part of the code is here:

```
id=request.QueryString("id")
name=request.Form("name")
sex=request.Form("sex")
age=request.Form("age")
logtime=date()  // I am not sure if this is correct 
sql="select * from table where id="&id
set rs=conn.execute(sql)
sql="update table set name='"+name+"', sex='"+sex+"', age='"+age+"', logtime='"+logtime+"' where id="&id // for the logtime='"+logtime+"', I think it is also not correct.
'response.Write sql
conn.execute(sql)
conn.close
set conn=nothing
```

Comment: Which database are you using? It seems likely that this could be handled by the database with a parameter query or stored procedure, which would be a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Classic ASP it's:

```
logtime=now()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried both, now() and date(), still now luck yet. Do you think there is any problem with the update section? It is keep telling me Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: '[string: "update table se"]'

Comment: For the "logtime" field in my access file, I have tried both text and date/time, but still not working right.

Comment: Post the generated SQL string. Maybe there is a syntax issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I tried again and use logtime=CStr(Now()), and it is working perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the other question you posted, your solution has a security risk of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and that you ought to use parametized SQL queries. In addition, your `conn.Execute(sql)` should really be `conn.Execute sql` or `Call conn.Execute(sql)`. In addition, by using parametized queries, date handling becomes better, for instance:

```
id = request.QueryString("id")
name=request.Form("name")
sex = request.Form("sex")
age = CInt(request.Form("age"))
logtime = Now

sql = "update user_table" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "set name = @name, sex = @sex, age = @age, logtime = @logtime" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "where id = @id" & vbCrLf

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = sql
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.Prepared = True
cmd.Parameters.Refresh 
cmd.Parameters("@name") = name
cmd.Parameters("@sex") = sex
cmd.Parameters("@age") = age
cmd.Parameters("@logtime") = logtime
cmd.Parameters("@id") = id
cmd.Execute
Set cmd = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

For access database you would have to follow below format

#YYYY-MM-DD# 
-- some versions will accept 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Happy coding!!